# Facebook app error or my mistake strange thing happened to me

Tags: facebook

I created a facebook application which create as new image and upload it to users albums but when they are using the app that image is uploading to my albums. that sounds funny but it is shocking to me how can their images can upload to me. please check my code if i made any mistakes.

```
     $access_token = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN';
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;
     $album_name = 'Klu report';  
     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => 'sai ram'
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     $album_id = $result->id;

     $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
      . $album_id ."/photos?"
      . "url=" . urlencode('https://yourkishore.com/facebook/'.$output)
      . "&message=" . urlencode('I got my Placements report get yours here : https://apps.facebook.com/yourkishore')
      . "&method=POST"
      . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
      echo '<html><body>';
      file_get_contents($graph_url);
      echo '</body></html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Which user Facebook API believes this photo should go to is directly tied to the `access_token`. Start debugging there. Put a few access_tokens from different users in the debugger [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see what you get.